# Ajax load duplicates entire page

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to refresh a div with jquery load(); but the load displays the correct information but duplicates entire parts of the page that arent in the div

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(this).attr('action'),
       cache: false,
       data: $("#uses_form").serializeArray(),
       success: function(data)
       {
            $('#uses_form_div').load('#uses_form_div');

       }
     });
return false; });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you are having a misunderstanding..

if you want to load an external url into the div block

```
$('#uses_form_div').load("./a.file");
```

will do it. see the [api docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Or if you are trying to load the ajax response of the $.ajax call into the div, it should be

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: $(this).attr('action'),
       cache: false,
       data: $("#uses_form").serializeArray(),
       success: function(data)
       {
            $('#uses_form_div').html(data); // see here

       }
});
```

**UPDATED according to comments below:**

if the case of an included page to be refreshed. I have two ways to recommend.

1. make the included file as a separate url and load it initially. so instead of `include` you will be loading it via jquery as the page loads by a jquery load call. and when you want to refresh it you can do   `$('#uses_form_div').load("./a.file");`
2. you can put it as include it self and when you need to update, make an ajx request get the data back. Here you have 2 choice. You can build the dom at server and give html as ajax response and simply `$("#uses_form_div").html(data)` or get the response as json
   and build your dom at client side and load it via same `$("#uses_form_div").html(data)`.

Comment: I would like my div to repopulate with the user entered data. is there a way to refresh an include?

Comment: can't .load() file with get variable?

Comment: @i dint get what you are telling .. please show code in question.

Comment: in the .load file I have a get variable but i figured it out.. you have to set it in the link in the .load() reference.... The include and .load should theoretically have the same functionality right?

Comment: no at all.. `jquery load` and `php include` are totally different. the php stuff gets it rendered at server and gives you the complete page. `jquery load` will be called via javascript while browser is loading up the page. It invokes a new ajax request for a external page and the response content gets loaded into the targeted `dom element`. as you can see the there was no 2nd http request in case of the php way.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it is working well... maybe i can explain what i am doing i have a form with multiple options and appended rows, and when submitted i would like it to repopulate the fields instantaneously with echoed fields from the database... is the load method the best or is there  another method which you find better?

Comment: if i were you, i would make an ajax call, then get data as json, then process it and render on success of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem but finally found the answer

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function recp() {
  setInterval(function() 
  {
    $("#result").load(location.href+ ' #my');
  });
}
</script>
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div id="my"><?php echo date('a:i:s'); ?></div>
</div>
```